# If I reset my phone will I lose updated windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10-upgrade

I have updated my windows phone from Windows 8 to Windows 10. If I reset my phone will I lose the updated Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

No, you will not go back to Windows Phone 8 when you reset your phone. The phone will be reset to a clean install of the latest installed Windows 10 Mobile version.

Comment: This used to happen when windows 10 was newly launched and in its couple of months of release. But now when you will reset your phone it wont go back to windows 8 instead you will get clean windows 10.